# php - foreign characters not showing correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to do so foreign characters is showing correctly at my website.

When I try to write: "Português" it will output this:

```
Portugu&Atilde;&ordf;s
```

The code I use is:

```
$name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($f['forum_name']));
```

I also tried this:

```
$name = html_entity_decode(stripslashes(stripslashes($f['forum_desc'])));
```

But that gave me:

```
PortuguÃªs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: $f is coming from this:

```
$sf=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_cats WHERE forum_type='0' AND forum_type_id='".$h['forum_id']."'");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Where is `$f['forum_name'])` coming from ?

Comment: What made you think that `stripslashes()` would be of any help at all? It's entirely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I've updated my question with where $f is coming from. About stripslashes - sometimes my text generated \\\\ to it. That's why I added it.

Comment: Try with adding the encoding to htmlspecialchars function htmlspecialchars( $string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, make sure your PHP program file is saved with UTF-8 encoding. (a decent editor should allow you to set the encoding)
- Second, make sure that your HTML code specifies UTF-8 encoding: Make sure you have the following meta tag in your HTML head:

  ```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  ```
- Thirdly, throw away all that entity decoding and especially throw away the `stripslashes()`.

You may also need to do further work to make sure that everything in your system is using UTF-8 encoding (eg the database, other input files).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of utf-8 decode

```
<?php
echo utf8_decode("Português");//Português
```

**EDIT** : (From your latest question update)
Add this on top of your PHP code.

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Doing like this: $name = utf8_decode($f['forum_name']); Doesn't work. Output this: PortuguÃªs

Comment: You need to add this if you are using mysqli, Just specify the charset as utf-8 like this. `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($f['forum_name'], "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8", $f['forum_name']); ?>
```

Use `mb_detect_encoding()` to detect the charset type of your strings and `iconv()` to convert string to requested character encoding.

You can refer [**mb_detect_encoding**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php%5d) and [**iconv**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) on official documentation site.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: are you setting your database connection to utf-8?

Comment: Like this: `$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);` 
 `mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');`